# AWS Latency Metrics Logging Issue Spring Boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, logging

I am trying to log aws latency metrics on the application server. I have tried implementing the last **Latency Metrics Logging** section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html

As mentioned in the instructions there:

I am setting the following while initializing ApplicationContext:

```
AwsSdkMetrics.enableDefaultMetrics();
AwsSdkMetrics.setMetricNameSpace("SNSMetricsLog");
AwsSdkMetrics.setCredentialProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

I am using the following in log.properties:

```
log.folder=log
log.app.fileName=application.log
log.metric.fileName=metric.json
log.level=DEBUG
log.app.batch.fileName=batch.log
log.app.skippedMsg.fileName=skipped.log
log.logger.com.amazonaws.latency=DEBUG
```

Even after making these changes, the AWS latency metrics are not coming although I am able to see other DEBUG logs.

Comment: Have you tried `AwsSdkMetrics.isDefaultMetricsEnabled()` to check if its enabled after you have setup those? Also, is there any application logs that can given an input about it getting connected?

Comment: AwsSdkMetrics.isDefaultMetricsEnabled() is giving false. Application logs are there and SNS is getting connected and able to publish to SNS. It's just that metrics is not coming.

Comment: If your `AwsSdkMetrics.isDefaultMetricsEnabled()` is returning false, then it could mean you have not set the command line property for was credential files? The code for `isDefaultMetricsEnabled()` is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/metrics/AwsSdkMetrics.java#L290), that states, to read the property. Did you follow this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/generating-sdk-metrics.html ?

Comment: Using env variable AwsSdkMetrics.isDefaultMetricsEnabled() is giving true. But the latency metrics logs are still not visible

Comment: How frequently are you checking the metrics and is your application running continuously? According to this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/enabling-metrics-with-the-aws-sdk-for-java/, `metric data points will get generated, queued for statistical summary, and then uploaded asynchronously to Amazon CloudWatch about once every minute`